# "No route matches" - Ruby/Rails/Cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, cucumber

I'm doing the Berkeley Software as a Service course, and just can't work out what is needed to create "a RESTful route for Find Similar Movies".

I have this in my movies_controller:

```
def find_by_same_director
  @movies = Movie.find_by_director params[:id]
end
```

I'm trying as many variants of this in routes.rb as possible:

```
match 'movies/find_by_same_director/:id' => 'movies#find_by_same_director'
```

But whatever I do I keep running into the same error when I run my Cucumber:

```
No route matches
{:action=>"find_by_same_director",:controller=>"movies", :id=>1}
(ActionController::RoutingError)
```

I'm new to Rails so I imagine I've just failed to correctly understand what it is one has to do to have a controller action recognized as a route. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: Everything looks correct. Can you post the Cucumber code that's failing?

Comment: @Brandan, hmm, yes, of course I could just have gotten myself all mixed up in Cucumber: more than likely. I'll edit with some of the more suspect stuff I've written in support/paths.rb...

Comment: Could you run `rake routes` at the command prompt and paste the output in?  Just so we can see that there is a route defined.

Comment: How can I check the existence of the route via RSpec?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `config/routes.rb` should have something like or simmilar:

```
match '/movies/:id/directors' => 'movies#same_directors', :as => 'same_directors'
```

Your `app/controllers/movies_controller.rb` should have an action with the same name!

```
def same_directors
end
```

You should create a view like this:

```
`app/views/movies/same_directors.html.haml`
```

And for cucumber, your `features/support/paths.rb` should have this line or simmilar:

```
when /^the Similar Movies page for "(.*)"$/
  same_directors_path(Movie.find_by_title($1))
```

This is the rails app cook recipe and the cucumber setup for knowing the exatcly route!

Comment: Thanks! Adding :as to the match in routes.rb seems to allow find_by_same_director_path to work in features/support/paths.rb, which I suppose is what I was missing. I'm finding the Coursera course a bit frustrating in that it seems to be fairly necessary to go away and learn Rails and Cucumber independently - when I was hoping to be able to learn (at least enough to scrape by) THROUGH the course...

Comment: @thesunneversets We are here for that! You're Welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

```
match 'movies/find_by_same_director/:id' => 'movies#find_by_same_director'
```

Becomes:

```
match '/movies/find_by_same_director/:id' => 'movies#find_by_same_director'
```